# Launching phone call in background without displaying anything

Tags: java, android

I wonder, is there an option in `Android` of application to run recorder or simply call to phone number in background, without displaying it to the user, and after timer finish it?

Comment: I am sure you are wanting to do this for a good reason, but other people may create an app and then turn on these features for ill reasons. E.g. App ABC will call Australia and make spam calls and the user does not even know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't silently call from an android app.

Comment: Call I can't,what about voice recorder? it can run as service not?